# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException while querying SQLite in Android code

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Kindly note that I am trying to retrieve values from table in SQLite DB in my android app, on a button click event and present it through a ListView.I am able to insert records into the table on same event.Although it throws the following error:

```
`05-15 11:54:16.721: W/System.err(1834): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
05-15 11:54:16.721: W/System.err(1834):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:434)
05-15 11:54:16.721: W/System.err(1834):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
05-15 11:54:16.721: W/System.err(1834):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
`
```

Follwing is the chunk of code I am using to Insert,Retrieve and Display the records from table in ListView:

```
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              event=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
              message=ed1.getText().toString();
              MainActivity.myDataBase.openDatabase("/data/data/org.mithil.appname/databases/tablename", null,MainActivity.myDataBase.OPEN_READWRITE);
              MainActivity.myDataBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                      MainActivity.tablename +
                        " Values ('"+ finalnumber +"','"+ name +"','"+ message +"','"+ event +"','"+ ldate +"');");
              Cursor cu = MainActivity.myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM " + MainActivity.tablename + " WHERE Date =" + ldate +";" , null);
              cu.moveToFirst();
              Log.d("first rec", cu.toString());
              while(cu!=null)
              {
                  try{
                  lstitem.add(cu.getString(0));
                  cu.moveToNext();
                  }
                  catch(Exception e)
                  {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
```

All this is happening in a button click.The insertions are getting reflected in table but the 'Select' is not.I reckon something is wrong with moving the cursor.The table consist of five fields off which I want to retrieve only one ie. 'Name' field and add the name into the ListView.Kindly correct me where I am going wrong.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi thanks for suggestion.there is no hasNext() method for Cursor class.But there is a method called 'isAfterLast()' which points to the position after last row.I will try using that.Will let you know.

Comment: Had that comment there for a second before I i removed it. was thinking about python. :P

Comment: Thank you @Gjordis,your solution helped.Much appreciated.May the force be with you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(cu !isAfterLast()){...
```

Shouldn't go out of bounds then.
It can be not-null and still go out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the values from the cursor like this

```
if(cu.moveToFirst())
{
do
{

}while(cu.moveToNext())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this just get the cursor count and set it as a condition in for loop and iterate through it.

```
 for(int i=0;i<cr.getCount;i++)
{
//do your stuff here;
cr.moveToNext();
}
```